# In Firebase when using push() How to store in my database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to connect the Metadata from an image to the database and this error occures: TypeError: firebase.database is not a function. 
I have read the firebase explanation but it is quite confusing for me but i manage to figure out the following code:

```js
var postKey = firebase.database().ref('Posts/').push().key; // error is here
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    var updates = {};
    var postData = {
    url: downloadURL,
    user: user.uid
};
updates['Posts/'+postKey] = postData;
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Can somone notice my mistake, because i have been wondering a few hours and i know it is sth very stupid

And here is how i imported firestore to the project:

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    
// Your web app's Firebase configuration

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBRNh8os4J9VJoAK7Jjgs-tEqJxyCmIBtg",
  authDomain: "varnamedi.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://varnamedi.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "varnamedi",
  storageBucket: "varnamedi.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "636325306958",
  appId: "1:636325306958:web:bf10f1eb7dd9f88c88591f",
  measurementId: "G-2GE9N5TGPD"
  };
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

  //Display or not

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Comment: Can you add to your question how you add Firebase to your JavaScript project (See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=2)?

Comment: i have already imported Firebase to my javascript

Comment: Can you please show how you did it. It may be the cause of your error. Thanks.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Just edited the post you can check, thanks for helping!

Comment: In the future, please do a web search using the error message you find.  There is usually lots of existing information out there that is really easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

you have declared in your project different Firebase services (i.e. you have imported different Firebase SDK like the `firebase-firestore`, `firebase-auth` or `firebase-storage` ones) but **not** the Firebase Realtime Database one.

You need to add this line:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

---

Note that you may remove the following line if you are not using Firestore:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

As a matter of fact, Firestore and Firebase Realtime Database are two different database services offered by Firebase.

Comment: So one way to solve your problem is to do `user.uid` and all dependent code within `if (user) {...}`.

Comment: thank, i already voted for you comment. I asked about the user because it was strange to that i already have the  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log('user logged in:', user);
  } else {
    console.log('user logged out');
  }
});

and it still shows me the erorr : Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined

Comment: "thank, i already voted for you comment." -> Thanks :-) I actually meant to upvote my answer, in addition to accept it :-) (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: When you do `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {})` the `user` variable is only defined within the callback function (not outside of it). Note that the doc also says "You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the `currentUser` property. If a user isn't signed in, `currentUser` is null."